# cxGrid edit added unbound column

Tags: delphi, devexpress, tcxgrid

I have added an unbound column in my cxGrid and set its property to checkbox.
However at runtime I can not check or uncheck it in the displayed rows. It remains unresponsive.
How can I correct that ? Is there a setting that controls this ?

Comment: Have you tried the DevExpress KB Article How to set up an unbound item in a data-aware View (https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/a1095/)?

Comment: @Brian I followed that but still does not work. I can check it but soon as I move to next record it gets unchecked.